# Detection of condensation on automotive glass

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, resistance, automotive

Wondering if anyone has done this or can add to my theory, my idea is to use a microcontroller to measure the resistance of a heated car windscreen using the pre-existing copper conductors to detect the moisture level on the windscreen i.e mist/condensation.

In theory it may work as soil moisture sensors do exactly the same thing however the accuracy and reliability may be questionable anyone any thoughts?

Comment: water is an insulator contaminated with metallic ions in soil. How clean is your glass?

Comment: I would invest into optical detection instead...

Comment: Bearing in mind that this is on a car which could potentially have many different contaminants on it that variable would be uncontrollable I am going in the assumption that as in moisture sensors for plants the resistance drops as moisture increases however I am guessing you may have to correlate data with other variables such as temperature and humidity.

Comment: Yes I read about that but wondering if you could avoid sensors that may over time mist up themselves or get dirt or other contaminants on imparing results

Comment: I have never seen heated windshields where the (nichrome) conductors were open to the elements

Comment: don't soil sensors use capacitance changes, not resistive?

Answer (score 0):

The best and most dependable way would be an infra-red detector. Put the IR LED outside the window in a bottom corner, and the sensor on the inside of the car window positioned so the IR LED hits it. Leave a 1 inch gap from the IR LED to the glass so any condensation will build up there.

Use infra-red (or red) because water molecules block/absorb the red colors the most. Water is somewhat transparent to green/bluish light so they would not work unless you wanted both for an 'A vs. B' comparison. Or use an IR LED on both bottom corners of the window for an 'A vs. B' comparison.

The sensor should have a voltage output that drives a simple display on your dashboard, and be powered by 12 VDC if possible, just to keep things simple.

Calibration consist of measuring the level on the display with a very clean window and IR LED lens or cover. To get consistent readings be sure the window and the IR LED cover stay clean. *Fog/condensation will cause the reading to be lower*. Condensation also attracts dirt and dust so you may have to clean often if fog and condensation happen often.

EDIT: You *will* need to pay attention as to how the weather other than fog affects your readings. If you live up north the UV index can be high (maybe a small sun shield?) and the freezing cold may cause readings to drift. In the south the intense heat may cause a drift in the readings, so you will have to learn how it behaves with just fog and condensation vs. how other types of weather affect your readings.

Comment: Then there's the inconvenience of the sun shining and ruining your calibration ...

Comment: @Transistor. Yes, especially up north where the UV light is more intense. It is doable, but may need constant maintenance. In the south high temperatures may cause a drift in the readings. An imperfect setup at best, considering weather conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I just though of using the  scattering loss of light to indicate fog or freezing.

Using pulsed narrow IR beam emitter recessed behind narrow aperture holes on both with << 1 deg beamwidth.

The PD would use a daylight blocking filter, it could be done by reflecting across the inner surface of the window from outside the edges.

One could offset the beams and use the increase of brightness from scattering on a wider beam or loss of a narrow beam.  I suspect a wide scattering of the glass would be best.

Come to think now I think that's how my Mercedes speeds up the delay time windshield wipers from outside rain scattering light.